# What is the type of (==) with only one argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am given the following function and I have to give the most general type.

```
\x y -> (==)(map x y)
```

My approach is on the picture attached. The solution is different tho, it is

```
Eq b=> (a->b)->[a]->[b]->Bool
```

I do no understand where the [b] is coming from.

Update: I found out that the type of

```
\x y z -> (==)(map x y) z
```

Is the same as the type of my original function. 
So basically you can drop one of the arguments in the lambda function but it's still kinda there, as we know that (==) takes 2 arguments? But why?

[image]

Comment: Please convert the picture to text.

Comment: Lookup the term "eta reduction"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: it originates from the fact that the two operands of the `(==)` should have the same type.

Let us derive the type for `\x y -> (==) (map x y)`. We can look up the types for `(==) :: Eq c => c -> c -> Bool` and `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.

Since we apply `x :: d` and `y :: e` to `map`, that thus means that:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
x   ::    d
y   ::              e
-----------------------------
d ~ a -> b, e ~ [a]
```

So `x` has type `a -> b`, and `y` has type `[a]`.

Now we know that `map x y` has type `map x y :: [b]`. This is the parameter in a function application with `(==)`. We thus can derive the type for `(==) (map x y)` as:

```
(==)    :: Eq c =>  c -> c -> Bool
map x y ::         [b]
----------------------------------
c ~ [b]
```

So since `c ~ [b]`, this thus means that the type of `(==) (map x y) :: Eq [b] => [b] -> Bool`, and thus that `\x y -> (==) (map x y)` has type `\x y -> (==) (map x y) :: Eq [b] => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] -> [b]`.

Since it holds that:

> `instance Eq a => Eq [a]`

We can thus change the type constraint from `Eq [b]` to just `Eq b`.

> Update: I found out that the type of
>
> ```
> \x y z -> (==)(map x y) z
> ```

Since `(==) (map x y)` is a function, the above indeed holds, since this is the opposite of [*η-reduction* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion).

Comment: Do you mean \x y -> (==) (map x y) :: Eq [b] => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] -> *BOOL*. ?